# Not able to set value using HtmlUnitDriver + Geb

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geb, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to fill a value in the text field and click a button using selenium + HtmlUnitDriver + Geb.

Following is my code

```
import geb.Browser;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
RoFlow {
 def browser = new Browser()
 browser.driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
 Browser.drive {
     def websiteOpened = false
     go "http://www.google.com"
     websiteOpened = $(name: "q").isDisplayed()
     println websiteOpened  // printing true
     println $("input",name:"q")
        // printing [<input class="lst lst-tbb sbibps" id="lst-ib" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" aria-label="Search" />]
     $("input",name:"q").value("Groovy")  // throwing exception
     $("input",name:"btnG").click()

 }
}
```

when i run the above code, i'm getting the following exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput.setValueAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/Page;
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.clear(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:268)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValue(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:741)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValues_closure40(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:711)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.setInputValues(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:710)
    at geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator.value(NonEmptyNavigator.groovy:448)
    at iobtest.run_closure1$_closure2(iobtest.groovy:16)
    at iobtest.run_closure1$_closure2(iobtest.groovy)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:1061)
    at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:1031)
    at iobtest.run_closure1(iobtest.groovy:10)
    at iobtest.run_closure1(iobtest.groovy)
    at com.bankbazaar.roboarm.delegate.RoboArmScriptExecutor.executeBBFlow_closure1$_closure2(RoboArmScriptExecutor.groovy:24)
    at iobtest.run(iobtest.groovy:7)
```

1. geb - 0.13.1
2. selenium - 2.44.0
3. selenium-htmlunit-driver - 2.44.0

let me know if i'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Check if $("input",name:"q") is actually finding the element or not?

Comment: The error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` says it all. `HtmlUnitDriver` didn't open a session.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use htmlunit driver. It's extremely limited and not fit for testing modern, js heavy apps.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError mean you have an incompatible combination of the selenium html unit driver and the html unit driver itself.

Comment: @TarunLalwani,line println $("input",name:"q") in the code is printing the element as shown in the code

Comment: @DebanjanB, HtmlUnitDriver is able to find the elements, which means it is opening a session.

Comment: Please use latest version (with different maven `artifactId`), which is [2.27](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver)